# Intercooler JS not sending form data correctly on Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django, safari

I am developing a social media-type web application, and so far everything has been working fine on Chrome and Firefox. I recently discovered a bug on Safari (both iOS and macOS) where form data is not correctly being sent when I send an AJAX request using intercooler JS.

The issue was found first when I realized that Safari was not allowing friend requests to be accepted when people respond from their notifications area. Here is the relevant HTML for when people accept/deny a friend request from their notifications

```
<form method="post" ic-post-to="{% url 'respond-request' item.sender.pk %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <button name="accept" type="submit">Accept</button>
    <button name="decline" type="submit">Decline</button>
</form>
```

In my Django View, I do two two things whenever someone responds to a friend request:

1. Remove the notification/friend request entirely
2. Add the users as friends if and only if `accept` is in `request.POST`

This is the relevant code

```
# Remove notification
notification = Notification.objects.get(receiver=request.user, sender=userProfile, action="friend_request_received")
notification.delete()

# Remove the request
request.user.friend_requests_received.remove(userProfile)

# If yes, then add to friends and remove from request
if 'accept' in request.POST:
    request.user.friends.add(userProfile)
```

This is working as intended on Chrome and Firefox. When someone clicks `accept` on the above HTML, the users become friends. When they click `decline`, then the request is removed and they do not become friends.

The strange thing is that if the above HTML is used on Safari, the request is removed but the users do not become friends. I have printed `request.POST` in Django and can confirm the POST data is being sent as I expect from Chrome, but not Safari. **Safari simply does not include `accept`, or any form data at all, in the AJAX request sent via intercooler, making the if statement in my above code never fire.**

Is this simply a bug with Intercooler? I saw on various posts people talking about using jQuery to modify the AJAX call in certain ways, but I could not find anything related to using Intercooler. Is there a way to achieve what I want on Safari using only Intercooler and AJAX?

Comment: Out of curiosity, have you tried putting an explicit `value` attribute on the button: `<button name="accept" type="submit" value="accept">Accept</button>`

Comment: Yes, that was something I forgot to mention I tried. Didn't help :(